# How to copy video files from OS X to iPad over Wi-Fi?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, wifi, file-transfer, copy-paste

I'd like to copy video files from my computer (OS X) to iPad over WLAN. I'd prefer simply share a folder on OS X and then be able to copy files from that folder when iPad is connected to the same WLAN.

What solutions there exists for this (apps, OS X native share)?

I have been using Dropbox, but it's too slow as it is round-tripping the file transfer through the internet connection, not the WLAN.

Videos are MP4 files, so they don't need to be converted.

Comment: I tested Dropcopy - it installs on OSX and iPad from App Store and allows simple file copying. It does it jobs, but 1) doesn't run on background on iPad 2) doesn't have transfer queue - you need to copy one file at time 3) doesn't have automatic sync features.

Comment: On the positive side, Dropcopy has cool visual animation which reminds me of hyperspace gates of various sci-fi shows.

Comment: Also looks like Dropcopy video player has been designed to preview files - though it has normal QuickTime full-screen player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AirSharing](http://avatron.com/apps/air-sharing) is a swiss army knife of turning any iOS device into a wireless file server. There are many others, but this program has three versions that have stood the test of time.

The "copy when connected" nut will be harder to crack. Unless someone steps up with a ready made solution, you will have to set up SMNP monitoring of your router and trigger a sync when the iPad MAC address is logged as joining the network. You could also poll bonjour locally, but SNMP seems more elegant to me since it will log and push that join without constant monitoring on the mac end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't even need to copy it. you can stream those video directly on your ipad with [AirVideo](http://www.inmethod.com/)

Comment: My purpose is to take videos along with the device for offline use.